# Changing Labels for a Single DAC Field Used Multiple Times

Tags: acumatica

My scenario involves fetching data from a table that returns multiple results to be displayed. My problem is that when I add the fields on the screen, the labels are all the same. I am pulling notes from 3 different screens onto one screen to display for the user. The notes are from a Sales Order, Customer, and Inventory Item. The data is being pulled correctly for each screen, but the label for each text box is "NoteText." I would like to change these labels to more accurately reflect which screen the note is from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you'll want to use a Cache Attached event handler for the fields in question.  CacheAttached event handlers allow you to change the attributes of a field within the graph.

[PXUIField(DisplayName = "SO Notes")]
protected void SOOrder_NoteText_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{}

Comment: How would I use this to set the titles of the other two notes on the same page coming from Customer and Inventory Item?

Comment: You would add a cacheattached event handler for each note field and edit the displayname appropriately

Comment: Can you write a CacheAttached function for a column in a joined table?

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: Could you please give an example of how you would construct the _CacheAttached() function using a joined table from a View made with PXSelectJoin? An example being BaseTable.JoinedTable__JoinedField.

Comment: The example I give above is the only one you need.  Don't worry about how the field is joined in your view.  Check the Source code for more examples.

Comment: Alright, the reason I asked for a specific example using that is because the code above does not work for that example that I have in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This may be specific to my situation, but I found a solution. What I am doing is suppressing the generated titles and customizing RowSelecting() of the DAC to add my own titles within the NoteText based on the note's GraphType parameter. I have all other parameters to filter down to the three notes I would need to display for that specific page. I use the GraphType to insert the text in front of the note to generate my own label for it.